# Why does adding "sleep 1" in an after hook cause this Rspec/Capybara test to pass?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, capybara, capybara-webkit

I'm using rails 4.0.5, rspec 2.14.1, capybara 2.2.1, capybara-webkit 1.1.0 and database_cleaner 1.2.0.  I'm seeing some weird behavior with the following feature test (which simulates a user viewing a comment on a post, hovering over an icon to make a menu appear, and clicking a menu item to delete the comment):

```
let(:user){create(:user)}
let(:post){create(:post, author: user)}
let!(:comment){create(:comment, post: post, author: user)}

...

it "can delete a comment" do
  assert(page.has_css? "#comment-#{comment.id}")
  find("#comment-#{comment.id}-controls").trigger(:mouseover)
  find("#comment-#{comment.id} .comment-delete a").click
  assert(page.has_no_css? "#comment-#{comment.id}")
end
```

This test fails about 80% of the time, always due to some record being retrieved from the database as `nil`-- I get `NoMethodError: undefined method X for nil:NilClass`, for various values of X.  Sometimes the nil is the comment that's being deleted, sometimes it's the post that the comment's attached to, sometimes it's the author of the comment/post.

If I add `sleep 1` to the end of the test, it passes:

```
it "can delete its own comment" do
  assert(page.has_css? "#comment-#{comment.id}")
  find("#comment-#{comment.id}-controls").trigger(:mouseover)
  find("#comment-#{comment.id} .comment-delete a").click
  assert(page.has_no_css? "#comment-#{comment.id}")
  sleep 1
end
```

It also passes if I put `sleep 1` in an `after` block.

Any idea why I get these NoMethodErrors, and/or why the test passes if I make it sleep for a second after all the work is done?

Comment: What line of code are the `NoMethodError`s springing from? It’s weird that putting `sleep` at the *end* fixes it, but Capybara race conditions are a common problem.

Comment: @BuckDoyle All the errors say `Failure/Error: Unable to find matching line from backtrace`, followed by references to various model/controller methods that get called by an AJAX request that's triggered when a comment is deleted.  Looks like it's a race condition, not between the Capybara assertion and the comment deletion but between the database teardown and the callback code that runs after the deletion.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suspect that it's possible in your application for the comment to disappear from the page (which is the last thing you're asserting) before it's deleted from the database. That means that the test can clean up before the deletion happens. If this is the case you can fix it by waiting for the actual deletion to happen at the end of the test. I have this method around (a reimplementation of [a method that was removed from Capybara 2 but is still sometimes necessary](http://www.elabs.se/blog/53-why-wait_until-was-removed-from-capybara))

```
def wait_until(delay = 1)
  seconds_waited = 0
  while ! yield && seconds_waited < Capybara.default_wait_time
    sleep delay
    seconds_waited += 1
  end
  raise "Waited for #{Capybara.default_wait_time} seconds but condition did not become true" unless yield
end
```

so I can do

```
wait_until { Comment.count == 0 }
```

in tests.

Another approach is to add Rack middleware that blocks requests made after the test ends. This approach is described in detail here: http://www.salsify.com/blog/tearing-capybara-ajax-tests I saw it do a very good job of addressing data leakage in a good-sized suite of RSpec feature specs.

Comment: Actually the comment always gets deleted before disappearing, but the disappearance triggers an AJAX callback that (I think) is racing with the database cleanup.  The approach you linked looks promising; I'll try it out.  Thanks!

Comment: Capybara.default_wait_time is now deprecated in favor of Capybara.default_max_wait_time

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara#asynchronous-javascript-ajax-and-friends

> When working with asynchronous JavaScript, you might come across
>   situations where you are attempting to interact with an element which
>   is not yet present on the page. Capybara automatically deals with this
>   by waiting for elements to appear on the page.

Comment: This doesn’t explain why putting sleep at the *end* fixes the problem, after any assertions have been made. That’s why I asked the original poster for more detail.

Comment: But does say that you should not use sleep. Why would you deliberately slow down your tests. Capybara deals with waiting for elements really well as per phoet