# How to resolve RSpec's deprecation warning about the new expect syntax?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara, rspec-rails, rspec3

When I run this RSpec example, it passes but I'm getting a deprecation warning.

```
context "should have valid detail for signup" do
  it "should give error for invalid confirm password" do
    find("#usernamesignup").set("Any_name")
    find("#mobile_number").set("1234567890")
    find("#emailsignup").set("mymail@yopmail.com")
    find("#passwordsignup").set("12345678")
    find("#passwordsignup_confirm").set("")
    find(".signin").click
    sleep 2
    page.should have_content "Confirm Password Does not Match"
  end
end
```

Here is the output:

Deprecation Warnings:

> Using `should` from rspec-expectations' old `:should` syntax without
>   explicitly enabling the syntax is deprecated. Use the new `:expect`
>   syntax or explicitly enable `:should` with `config.expect_with(:rspec)
>   { |c| c.syntax = :should }` instead. Called from
>   /home/rails/rails_nimish/Devise_use/spec/features/users_spec.rb:113:in
>   `block (4 levels) in '

[image]

How to resolve this warning?

**Update:solution**
I just replaced

> page.should have_content "Confirm Password Does not Match"

with:

```
expect(page).to have_content "Confirm Password Does not Match"
```

Comment: It would be better to enter the actual text of the warning in the body of your question. It would be easier to read and to find with Google.

Comment: I don't want to use should, because it is old syntax and I was looking for an expect(page) syntax.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

As the message says, you have two options:

- Explicitly configure RSpec to allow `.should`. Don't use that option; `.should` is deprecated and will likely not be as well supported in the future. If you really wanted to allow `.should`, though, you could do it by adding this to your spec_helper.rb (or editing the example configuration of rspec-mocks that is probably already there):

  ```
    RSpec.configure do |config|
      config.expect_with :rspec do |expectations|
        expectations.syntax = :should
      end
    end
  ```

  If you want to use both `expect` and `.should`, set

  ```
    expectations.syntax = [:expect, :should]
  ```

  But don't do that, pick one and use it everywhere in your test suite.
- Rewrite your expectation to

  ```
    expect(page).to have_content "Confirm Password Does not Match"
  ```

  If you have many specs whose syntax needs upgrading, you can use [the transpec gem](https://github.com/yujinakayama/transpec) to do it automatically.

Side note: Don't `sleep 2` before your expectation. [Capybara's `have_content` matcher waits for you.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25230581/634576)

Comment: yes, your second option answered my question. Thank you.

Comment: unfortunately, the gem you suggested (transpec) has unanswered unresolved Issues going back to 2017, eg, appears to be unmaintained

Answer (score 6):

I just replaced:

```
page.should have_content "Confirm Password Does not Match"
```

with:

```
expect(page).to have_content "Confirm Password Does not Match"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you decide to clean out the old syntax and you're a vim kind, you may find the following handy ;)

```
argdo %s/ \([^ ]\+\)\.should == \([^}]\+\)\( }\)\?$/ expect(\1).to eql(\2)\3/gc | update
argdo %s/should \(be_\w\+\)/expect(subject).to \1/gc | update
```