# Capybara/Selenium race condition when deleting record

Tags: selenium, ruby-on-rails-4, cucumber, capybara

I'm testing for deletion of records from an `ActiveRecord` class using Capybara/Selenium. The actual deletion is done using the Gherkin script (the xPath bit is so I can find the right user to delete):

```
When(/^I delete the other (.*)$/) do |role|
  visit '/users'
  page.evaluate_script('window.confirm = function() { return true; }')
  find(:xpath, %{//tr[td='Bob']/td[@class='list_actions']//a[@data-method='delete']}).click
end
```

Unfortunately when I check the list of users, Bob is still there. However, if I pause execution (using an `ask` statement) then when I resume sure enough Bob has gone. So it seems that Capybara is checking for Bob's existence before Selenium/Rails has got around to deleting him.

Googling for this, there seems to be a lot of confusion over whether Selenium waits on a `click` action, and all of the solutions I can find assume something is being *added* so they can wait until it appears -- not the case in my scenario.

So how can I get rid of this race condition -- make Selenium wait until the record has been deleted?

Comment: At the end of your deletion step, wait until the record is gone from the database.

Comment: Yes, that's what I want to do. How do I do it?

Comment: Like this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23555725/634576